# Comparing Elements of a Generic List

Tags: c#, generics, generic-list

I have a `TestClass<T>` that will evolve to a heap-based priority queue. The heap is `List<T>` type.

I was working on reordering code and I needed to compare the elements of the `List<T>`. As you can guess I received  `error CS0019: Operator < cannot be applied to operands of type T and T`.

I KNOW this is not surprising and C# generics are not C++ templates. So, I tried to constrain the `Type T` with an `IComparable`. But it did not help as well.

The suggestions I found (in order to solve this problem) were mostly creating a dummy class that defines such operators and constrain the `T` with this class. However, I did not find this solution very convenient.

So, are there any other ways to solve this?

Here's the related piece of code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class TestClass<T>
    where T : IComparable
{
    private List<T> heap;

    public TestClass(int maxSize)
    {
        this.heap = new List<T>(maxSize + 1);
    }

    private void ReorderUpwards(int nodeIndex)
    {
        while (nodeIndex > 1 && this.heap[nodeIndex / 2] < this.heap[nodeIndex])
        {
            nodeIndex /= 2;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No, the question [you deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49858413/comparing-elements-of-a-generic-list?noredirect=1) was duped to another that **is not Python**, look again.

Comment: More convenient than using IComparable and providing a method that actually does the comparison you want made?  You need to look at this a little harder.

Comment: @DavidG then could please tell me that if this is a duplicate of the question you suggest, how come "value.CompareTo(_minimumValue) >= 0" is not solving the problem?

Comment: That literally **is** the solution, now apply it to your code.

Comment: @DavidG and there is literally no other ways to do it without using this method?

Comment: Well what more do you need? What is the issue with doing it this way?

Comment: @DavidG I just wonder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `IComparable` and instead of using `>` and `<` use `CompareTo` method

```
value.CompareTo(value2) <= 0
```

Comment: Next time you answer, please make sure you're not answering an obvious duplicate.